# How to change the color scheme for html attributes in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, textmate, color-scheme

I'm working on a TextMate like color scheme for NetBeans (twilight), I'm almost done, there's only one thing left: I can't set the html attributes highlighting.

[image]

As you can see normal attributes are okay, but the ID and CLASS attributes are highlighted with this ugly greenish color. How can I fix that?

**Update**

[Here's](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14148878/netbeans_twilight_theme.zip) the link to the theme.

Comment: What are you trying to fix again? Is the id="wrong" being selected?

Comment: @William, yes. I don't want the ID and CLASS attributes to be highlighted with this ugly green color.

Comment: So, you want ID and CLASS attributes to show different colours than the other attributes?

Comment: No, I want exactly opposite thing. I want them to look exactly like other attributes. I don't know why NetBeans made them special by default.

Comment: Can you export your current theme so we can test it?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14148878/netbeans_twilight_theme.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer on Netbeans forum fixed it for me. 
http://forums.netbeans.org/post-91949.html#91949

Answer (score 7):

`id` and `class` attributes are special, because they are used in css, so if you have stylesheet in your project with `#wrong` declaration, you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click value of id/class attribute and you will be redirected to style declaration for this element.

To change it : Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Select your theme -> Syntax Tab -> Language: Cascading Style Sheet -> Category: Mark Occurrences

Comment: That helped... a little. Now when I place cursor on the class name or id name, background is ok. But when the cursor is moved to another place, it goes red or yellow again.

Answer (score 0):

On Netbeans 8.2, travel to:

"Tools" --> "Options" then travel to the "Fonts&Colors" parent tab. On this screen, on the "Syntax" sub-tab, select the Language "HTML". There is an option called "Css Embedded in HTML". Here you can change the background to the "inherit" such that your chosen theme background color will be recognized.